# xcb Initial window position

Tags: c++, xcb

I have a question regarding xcb windows. I am creating a xcb window using position and size. I get the following log messages, based on my implementation:

```
create: x:560 y:300 width:800 height:600
map window:
XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY: x:560 y:300 width:800 height:600
XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY: x:90 y:77 width:800 height:600
XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY: x:90 y:77 width:800 height:600
```

What I did

1. create window at specific position
2. map window
3. event loop

there are three configure notify events. the x/y position is relative to the parent window (parent is set to screen root and there is no reparent message because its a borderless window). I do a xcb_translate_coordinates using window and root as parent.
Why is the window moved to a different location?

Comment: Random guess would be "your window manager moves the window". At least I wouldn't except anything but your own program and the WM to configure the window. However, I cannot say why your WM does that since I do not even know which WM you are using nor how it decides about windows positions.

Comment: I am using Gnome from Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual box

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the window manager you're using stores the last position of the window before closing it and reestablish it when the application is re-launched and mapped onto the screen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).